# Possible to make a bathroom floor veneer with A4 Paper?

Tags: veneer

it would be nice to have a sandy beach photograph on the bathroom floor.

Is it possible to print A4 photos of sand from an online panorama and glue them to the floor, then perhaps varnish them and cover them with plastic varnish gloss to make the floor durable?

Is there a solution to making a strong floor veneer using an ordinary household printer?

Comment: That sounds... tacky.

Comment: I have seen discussions of using varnish over painted floors. And I've seen bartop-type epoxy treatments used to seal interesting papers to the tops of restaurant tables. Whether you could actually make photos meld together well enough (irregular edges, not straight or patterned lines, and make sure the lighting is even across the image, just as a start), apply a thick enough treatment over them, and keep the surface of that treatment even and smooth and transparent... I honestly don't know. Experiment on something else before committing the floor?

Comment: Yeah this thing is a nightmare from the execution stand point.  Also I would expect your paper is going to turn semi transparent when you apply your finish, exposing whatever lies beneath.

Comment: If you're going to go through that trouble, I'd suggest using actual sand (topped with an epoxy).

Comment: ..Or maybe go find a store that prints large signs or outdoor banners to print a large-format image for you, rather than trying to use tiny A4 pages. No matter what you do, please come back and post a photo of the finished project.. I'm sure it would help others contemplating a project like this.

Comment: Thanks for the realistic information! Using real sand would be very nice. I didnt manage to find info on how to make the sand layer prior to epoxying. indeed normal paper is too absorbent, and cellulose is generally a drab, tacky, un-reflective material, the wet cardboard effect. So indeed if it's paper it has to be special paper. i found this though. http://tinyurl.com/nk9b4el  http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/wallpaperon-the-floor-97701